# pip install package from requirements fails, "uses insecure transport scheme"

Tags: python, django, pip, requirements.txt

I'm trying to install [django-forms-builder](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-forms-builder/) via an entry in the requirements.txt file. When running

`pip install -r requirements.txt`

I receive the error

```
django-forms-builder/0.11.1 uses an insecure transport scheme (http). Consider using https if  has it available
django-forms-builder/ uses an insecure transport scheme (http). Consider using https if  has it available
Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement django-forms-builder==0.11.1 (from -r requirements.txt (line 33))
```

The message is very clear, it wants https, but I need to install the package anyway. It works when I install it separately outside of the requirements file with a simple

```
pip install django-forms-builder
```

so how can I force the requirements to accept it as well?

Comment: What does the line in your `requirements.txt` file look like?